# ASP.NET Core MVC - DataAnnotations localization shows the key name instead of the associated value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, localization, viewmodel, data-annotations

I've got a problem related to implementing localization in my ViewModels, we're using ASP.NET Core 2.0 and here is what I tried :

1) The viewmodel which I want to translate the DataAnnotations messages

```
public class ForgotPasswordViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "RequiredEmail")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredEmail", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ForgotPasswordViewModel))]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Veuillez entrer un email valide.")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

2) The code I added to Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
//...
       services.AddMvc().AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix).AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
//...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env){
//...
        var supportedCultures = new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
            new CultureInfo("fr-FR")
        };

        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions()
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("fr-FR"),
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
        });
//...
}
```

I have two resource files which are located in Resources/ViewModels/Account/

- ForgotPasswordViewModel.fr.resx
- ForgorPasswordViewModel.en.resx

with the following key/value at the moment :

- RequiredEmail => L'adresse email est nécessaire
- RequiredEmail => The mail address is necessary

Now, it doesn't work. What is shown instead of those messages is "RequiredEmail" which is the key name.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please post it as answer and accept it, when the 48 hours grace period ends as it may be interesting for others visitors. [Answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) is explicitly encouraged

Answer (score 2):

Alright, silly me. The path the original viewmodels are */Models/ViewModels/...* Therefore, the path to the resource files had to be 
*Resources/Models/ViewModels/Account/...* And not *Resources/ViewModels/Account/...*

I've simply blindly followed the Microsoft documentation and didn't think much about it.